# How to start Flume agent from java code

Tags: java, hadoop, flume

I am using hadoop 1.2.1 stable version in centos 6.5 and using apache flume 1.x i am running the flume agent and collecting the tweets in hdfs my flume.conf is

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = ******
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret =*****
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = *****
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = ***
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = CrudeOilPrice,Crude Oil,platts oil, Oil & Gas Journal 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = big data,hadoop
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://master:9000/user/flume/tweets/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

for run this i used command:

```
>bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent
```

now i am trying to run this with java program can any one give some idea i tried this code

```
public class fl {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        Process p;

        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/dsri/flume/bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent");

        p.waitFor();
         //p.exitValue();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) 
        {
        System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

but is not working for me..
now i am doing this code in java....

```
package dsri;
//package org.jai.flume.agent;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.flume.agent.embedded.EmbeddedAgent;


public class FlumeAgentServiceImpl {

    private static EmbeddedAgent agent;
    private void createAgent() {
        final Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();

        properties.put("channel.type", "memory");
        properties.put("channel.capacity", "200");
        properties.put("sinks", "sink1 sink2");
        properties.put("sink1.type", "avro");
        properties.put("sink2.type", "avro");
        properties.put("sink1.hostname", "collector1.apache.org");
        properties.put("sink1.port", "5564");
        properties.put("sink2.hostname", "collector2.apache.org");
        properties.put("sink2.port",  "5565");
        properties.put("processor.type", "load_balance");

        agent = new EmbeddedAgent("myagent");
        agent.configure(properties);
        agent.start();

    }

    public EmbeddedAgent getFlumeAgent() {
        if (agent == null) {
            createAgent();
        }
        return agent;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FlumeAgentServiceImpl f= new FlumeAgentServiceImpl();
        System.out.println(f.getFlumeAgent());
    }

}
```

But I am getting an exception...

```
org.apache.flume.FlumeException: NettyAvroRpcClient { host: collector1.apache.org, port: 5564 }: RPC connection error
at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.connect(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:161)
at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.connect(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:115)
at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.configure(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:590)
at org.apache.flume.api.RpcClientFactory.getInstance(RpcClientFactory.java:88)
at org.apache.flume.sink.AvroSink.initializeRpcClient(AvroSink.java:127)
at org.apache.flume.sink.AbstractRpcSink.createConnection(AbstractRpcSink.java:209)
at org.apache.flume.sink.AbstractRpcSink.start(AbstractRpcSink.java:289)
at org.apache.flume.sink.AbstractSinkProcessor.start(AbstractSinkProcessor.java:41)
at org.apache.flume.sink.LoadBalancingSinkProcessor.start(LoadBalancingSinkProcessor.java:134)
at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner.start(SinkRunner.java:79)
at org.apache.flume.agent.embedded.EmbeddedAgent.doStart(EmbeddedAgent.java:216)
at org.apache.flume.agent.embedded.EmbeddedAgent.start(EmbeddedAgent.java:114)
at dsri.FlumeAgentServiceImpl.createAgent(FlumeAgentServiceImpl.java:48)
at dsri.FlumeAgentServiceImpl.getFlumeAgent(FlumeAgentServiceImpl.java:53)
at dsri.FlumeAgentServiceImpl.main(FlumeAgentServiceImpl.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error connecting to collector1.apache.org/218.93.250.18:5564
at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.getChannel(NettyTransceiver.java:261)
at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.<init>(NettyTransceiver.java:203)
at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.<init>(NettyTransceiver.java:152)
at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.connect(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:147)
... 14 more
```

Comment: I find some information from here http://jaibeermalik.wordpress.com/2014/05/19/flume-gathering-customer-product-search-clicks-data-using-apache-flume/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also load the Flume Configuration file rather than writing it within the Java code.The same configuration could be used while starting your standalone Flume Agent.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] args = new String[] { "agent", "-nAgent",
            "-fflume.conf" };

    Application.main(args);

}
```

Where "Agent" is the name of your Flume Agent.
"flume.conf" is the configuration file which should be placed in the resources folder of your Java project.

Comment: Yes,the Flume Jar should be present in your classpath

Comment: Hi yesterday Your code was working fine but today i am getting this error 14/08/08 13:34:07 ERROR node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Failed to start agent because dependencies were not found in classpath. Error follows.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration

Comment: I have included all the flume jar file in my class path

Comment: Hi Gforz can you plz tell me how to stop this program after execution it continue running.....

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing that, try using an embedded agent (a far more elegant and cleaner solution). You create a `Map<String, String>` with the configuration of the Flume agent you wish to run, and then create an agent and configure it.

```
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
properties.put("channel.type", "memory");
properties.put("channel.capacity", "200");
properties.put("sinks", "sink1 sink2");
properties.put("sink1.type", "avro");
properties.put("sink2.type", "avro");
properties.put("sink1.hostname", "collector1.apache.org");
properties.put("sink1.port", "5564");
properties.put("sink2.hostname", "collector2.apache.org");
properties.put("sink2.port",  "5565");
properties.put("processor.type", "load_balance");

EmbeddedAgent agent = new EmbeddedAgent("myagent");

agent.configure(properties);
agent.start();

List<Event> events = Lists.newArrayList();

events.add(event);
events.add(event);
events.add(event);
events.add(event);

agent.putAll(events);

...

agent.stop();
```

You can find more information about it [here](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/flume-ng-1.3.0-cdh4.3.0/FlumeDeveloperGuide.html#embedded-agent).

Comment: Thanks for you reply I am doing research on your link some how i able to run your code n java but getting some exception.  org.apache.flume.FlumeException: NettyAvroRpcClient { host: collector1.apache.org, port: 5564 }: RPC connection error
 at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.connect(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:161)

Comment: Edit your post and add the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on the same problem. You can't use EmbeddedAgent here because it only support avro sink.